# Phoenix controller test, set request host

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I am making a multisite application. I want to set the request host on the connection prior to testing the controller. In Rails we could do this using

```
before :each do
  request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = '/'
end
```

Can someone suggest how to do the same in Phoenix?

**Edit 1**: I could set the host using
`conn |> put_req_header("host", "abc.com")`, but that did not change the `host` property in the `conn` object. It still points to "www.example.com"

**Edit 2**: I also tried

```
test "creates resource and redirects when data is valid", %{conn: _conn} do
  struct_url = %{Myapp.Endpoint.struct_url | host: "abc.com"}
  conn = post(conn, registration_url(struct_url, :create, user: @valid_attrs))
  assert redirected_to(conn) == "/"
end
```

But i got the following error:

```
$ mix test test/controllers/registration_controller_test.exs                                                                                 1) test creates resource and redirects when data is valid (Myapp.RegistrationControllerTest)
     test/controllers/registration_controller_test.exs:14
     ** (RuntimeError) expected action/2 to return a Plug.Conn, all plugs must receive a connection (conn) and return a connection
     stacktrace:
       (myapp) web/controllers/registration_controller.ex:1: Myapp.RegistrationController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
       (myapp) lib/phoenix/router.ex:255: Myapp.Router.dispatch/2
       (myapp) web/router.ex:1: Myapp.Router.do_call/2
       (myapp) lib/myapp/endpoint.ex:1: Myapp.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
       (myapp) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: Myapp.Endpoint.call/2
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:193: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
       test/controllers/registration_controller_test.exs:16
```

registration_controller.ex line 1 is `defmodule Myapp.RegistrationControllerTest do`

**Edit 3**:
Create action of `registration_controller.ex`

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    user_changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    if user_changeset.valid? do
      Repo.transaction fn ->
        user = Repo.insert!(user_changeset)
        user_site = Ecto.Model.build(user, :user_sites, site: site_id(conn))
        Repo.insert!(user_site)

        conn
          |> put_flash(:info, "Your account was created")
          |> put_session(:current_user, user)
          |> redirect(to: "/")
      end
    else
      conn
        |> render("new.html", changeset: user_changeset)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `Plug.Conn` is a struct, if you need to change the host you can use the [map update syntax](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%25%7B%7D/1):

```
conn = %{conn | host: "abc.com"}
```

If you want to change a key in a pipeline then use [Map.put/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Map.html#put/3):

```
conn =
  conn()
  |> put_header("content-type", "json")
  |> Map.put(:host, "abc.com")
```

If you want something to run before each test you can use [ExUnit.Callbacks.setup/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup/2)

```
setup do
  conn = %{conn() | host: "abc.com"}
  {:ok, conn}
end

test "foo", %{conn: conn} do
  get(conn, ...)
end
```

**Edit**

If you look at https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/3835473fcf3a554a616d1bbcd2639aa63893be2c/lib/plug/adapters/test/conn.ex#L7

You will see that the host is determined by:

```
host: uri.host || "www.example.com"
```

Which is called in Phoenix by https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/b9ebbc2b9241b59dcac5d9c6d66fa248efe68a9c/lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex#L200

This means that in order to get the host that you want, you need to specify it in the url, not the `conn`

Try this:

```
struct_url = %{MyApp.Endpoint.struct_url | host: "abc.com"}
conn = get(conn, foo_url(struct_url, :index)) #note foo_url not foo_path
```

**edit2**

The problem here is:

```
 Repo.transaction fn ->
    user = Repo.insert!(user_changeset)
    user_site = Ecto.Model.build(user, :user_sites, site: site_id(conn))
    Repo.insert!(user_site)

    conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Your account was created")
      |> put_session(:current_user, user)
      |> redirect(to: "/")
  end
```

The error is telling you that `action/2` should return a `Plug.Conn` however you are returning the result of the [transaction/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapter.Transaction.html#c:transaction/3) (which will be either `{:ok, value}` or `{error, value}`

This means your function will be returning `{:ok, conn}`

Try:

```
 Repo.transaction fn ->
    user = Repo.insert!(user_changeset)
    user_site = Ecto.Model.build(user, :user_sites, site: site_id(conn))
    Repo.insert!(user_site)
  end

  conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "Your account was created")
  |> put_session(:current_user, user)
  |> redirect(to: "/")
```

If you want to return a different result based on the transaction then I would move the whole section to a module function like `AccountService.create` and then use a case statement like:

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
  case MessageService.create(user_params) do
    {:ok, user} ->
      |> put_flash(:info, "Your account was created")
      |> put_session(:current_user, user)
      |> redirect(to: "/")
    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> render("new.html", changeset: user_changeset)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks conn did get updated in the setup, but when it gets to the test its host value gets resetted. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Thanks @Gazler , i tried it and updated my findings as "Edit 2" in the question. I am still getting an error :(

Comment: @PratikKhadloya Please post your create action for your controller.

Comment: @PratikKhadloya I'm pretty sure I have found the problem. See my latest edit.

Comment: Great! That worked @Gazler! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It turns out the first edit was actually unintended behavior in Plug. You no longer need to use the `foo_url(struct_url, :index)` workaround - you can use the standard `foo_path(conn, :index)` instead (when using plug's master branch; this should be a release soon). @Gazler, mind updating the answer?

Answer (score 2):

@chrismccord helped me find the answer. Needed to put it in the url.

`conn = get conn(), "http://example.com/"`

Comment: were you trying to message someone ? Can't see the reference.

Comment: No :) I was just trying to refer to Chris who created the Phoenix framework.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well. Although there doesn't seem to be a truly idiomatic way to solve the problem, I think the way I solved it is fairly clean. Note: this assumes you're only using subdomain hosts.

Firstly, update your config with a scope => host map so that your code stays DRY:

```
# config.exs

config :my_app, :scope_hosts,
  public: "www.",
  member_dashboard: "dashboard.",
  admin: "admin.",
  api: "api."
```

Create and add a `RouterHelpers` module to your `router.ex`:

```
# web/router.ex

import MyApp.RouterHelpers

scope host: get_scope_host(:admin), alias: MyApp, as: :admin do
  pipe_through [:browser, :admin_layout]

  get "/", Admin.PageController, :index
end

scope host: get_scope_host(:member_dashboard), alias: MyApp, 
  as: :member_dashboard do

  pipe_through [:browser, :member_dashboard_layout]

  get "/", MemberDashboard.PageController, :index
end

# web/helpers/router_helpers.ex

defmodule MyApp.RouterHelpers do
  def get_scope_host(scope) when is_atom(scope) do 
    Application.get_env(:my_app, :scope_hosts)[scope]
  end
end
```

Add a test helper to your `TestHelpers` module that will generate a full URL with the correct scope:

```
# test/support/test_helpers.ex

def host_scoped_path(path, scope) do
  host = MyApp.RouterHelpers.get_scope_host(scope)
  "http://#{host}myapp.test#{path}"
end
```

Finally, make use of this test helper in your controller tests:

```
# test/controllers/member_dashboard/page_controller_test.exs

test "shows member dashboard index page", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = get conn, action_url(conn, :index)
  assert html_response(conn, 200)=~ "member_dashboard"
end

defp action_url(conn, action) do 
  member_dashboard_page_path(conn, action) 
  |> host_scoped_path(:member_dashboard)
end
```